# chrome.identity.getAuthToken requires re-authorisation from the user, even though the user has already given permission to my app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

The chrome.identity API seems to require re-authorisation from user even though the user has given permission to my app in the past.

These are the steps being followed:

Get user authorisation for required scopes using

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(
{ account: { id: googleAccountId }, interactive: true }, 
(token) => { console.log("Access token", token); })
```

This brings up a dialog that prompts the user to authorize my app to access certain sensitive scopes. Once the user accepts it, I get the access token and use that to get user information.

Whenever I need an access token I call the
chrome.identity.getAuthToken. I understand chrome caches it internally, so I do not need to worry about calling it multiple times.

Every once in a while, it seems that the user will need to re-authorize my app. i.e. calling the chrome.identity.getAuthToken non interactively does not work. The user will need to be prompted again to authorize my app. This is the issue.

Expected behavior is:
Once the user has authorized my application and given permission to certain sensitive scopes unless there is a change in password / there is a need to access new scopes, the chrome.identity API should never ask the user to re-authorize my app.
This is an extremely poor user experience.

Notes

When the user was prompted to re-authorize my app again, I checked the permissions for my app for that user under accounts.google.com. My app already had the required permissions.
My understanding is that once a user has given permission to my app - it should never bring up the dialog again (for that user).

(My understanding of the chrome.identity API may be incorrect, if so please let me know).

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried calling `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` without specifying the account in the first parameter? That's how I use it and I've never had the re-authorisation issues you mention.

Comment: I have not. The reason being the user logs in the my website with a google account - and I want to use the same account here.

But I suspect this has something to do with it. 
I feel the this may be the issue and it may only work properly (i.e. without the above issue) - if the chrome profile and the account I am seeking auth from - are same. 

This is just my suspicion. I want to get a clear understanding. The documentation is awful and does not help.